# Webstorm new class/id on enter

Tags: pug, webstorm, stylus

I cannot believe I can't find any answers on Google. So here it goes.

When using Jade or Stylus indentation is very important. But how do I quickly start at a new identation? For example I have the following code in Jade:

```
block content
  .jumbotron
      img(src='http://placehold.it/1650x450')
```

Now I want to create another div class .news, so my code would look like this.

```
block content
      .jumbotron
          img(src='http://placehold.it/1650x450')
      .news
          H3 news!
```

How do I easily close the identation of .jumbotron so I can create a new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit Enter and then Shift+Tab (Edit/Unindent selection) 2 times to get the correct indentation
Note that smart indent doesn't work correctly for Jade now  ([WEB-6162](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6162))